# How to jump to an anchor / div per random button (jQuery mobile)?

Tags: button, html, random, jquery-mobile

I would like to make a random page effect in my jQuery Mobile app. Therefore I want to give the user a button to click, which jumps to / displays a random page-div on the site. thats all.

Answer (score 2):

```
var divs = jQuery.makeArray(document.getElementsByTagName('div'));
divs[Math.floor(Math.random()*(divs.size()+1))].doSomething();
```

Comment: thanks, but I'm an absolut beginner. Where should I put this code? Do I have to wrap it with something like <script type="text/javascript" ... ></script> in the head section?

Comment: And just one more question: what kind of code do I have to put on the imgage-button? thanks a lot! :-)