# Button link to random div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a photography course app in dreamweaver, and want users to be able to tap a button to randomly give them an assignment out of the numerous ones in the app.

All the various assignments are in separate div's, with separate div id's.
I've tried various javascript random link generators, but they don't link to the div ids...they are looking for the whole link (www.noelchenier.ca/#self) instead of the div ID's (#self).

Is there any way to do this?

This seems to be what this guy was asking too, but there is no explaination on where to use it?
[How to jump to an anchor / div per random button (jQuery mobile)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289615/how-to-jump-to-an-anchor-div-per-random-button-jquery-mobile)

Thanks for any possible help
Noel Chenier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be saying that you have a long page with lots of divs on it all displayed at once, and you want a button to jump down to a random one of those divs. If so this works:

```
<script>    
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#getAssignment").click(function() {
      var $divs = $(".assignment");
      if ($divs.length > 0) {
         window.location.href = "#" + $divs[ Math.floor(Math.random() * $divs.length) ].id;
      }
   });
});    
</script>

<input id="getAssignment" type="button" value="Get assignment">

<div id="a1" class="assignment">Assigment 1</div>
<div id="a2" class="assignment">Assigment 2</div>
<div id="a3" class="assignment">Assigment 3</div>
<div id="a4" class="assignment">Assigment 4</div>
```

Essentially it gets a list of all divs with the "assignment" class and then selects one at random to move to by setting the `location.href` to "#" plus the div id - this means the hash part of the url will change in the address bar so the user can bookmark that particular assignment.

However, selecting a random assignment from a bunch that are all displayed seems a bit strange when the user could just browse through the list themselves. It would make more sense to me to start out by hiding all of the assignments and then just show a random one each time the button is clicked. Using the same html as above:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var $assignments = $(".assignment");
   $assignments.hide();
   $("#getAssignment").click(function() {
      $assignments.hide();
      if ($assignments.length > 0)
         $($assignments[Math.floor(Math.random()*$assignments.length)]).show();
   });
});
```

**UPDATE**

From your last comment, I wonder if you're trying to use the same `id` attribute for more than one element? That won't work because each `id` needs to be unique.

If the idea is to have several container divs with a button in each that is supposed to randomly select a div from within that container, try giving `class="getAssignment"` in the buttons instead of `id=...`, then code something like this:

```
<script>    
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".getAssignment").click(function() {
      var $divs = $(this).parent().find(".assignment");
      if ($divs.length > 0) {
         window.location.href = "#" + $divs[ Math.floor(Math.random() * $divs.length) ].id;
      }
   });
});    
</script>
<div>
   <input class="getAssignment" type="button" value="Get assignment">
   <div id="a1" class="assignment">Assigment 1</div>
   <div id="a2" class="assignment">Assigment 2</div>
   <div id="a3" class="assignment">Assigment 3</div>
   <div id="a4" class="assignment">Assigment 4</div>
</div>
<div>
   <input class="getAssignment" type="button" value="Get assignment">
   <div id="b1" class="assignment">Assigment 7</div>
   <div id="b2" class="assignment">Assigment 8</div>
   <div id="b3" class="assignment">Assigment 9</div>
   <div id="b4" class="assignment">Assigment 10</div>
</div>
```

The click handler is assigned to all elements with class of "getAssignment", then the code `$(this).parent().find(".assignment")` takes the parent div of the clicked button and finds any ".assignment" divs within it.

Comment: Thanks nnnnn for the coding!  I put it in, but it was still looking for an html file.  I changed:

window.location.href = "#" + $divs[ Math.floor(Math.random() * $divs.length) ].id;

to 
window.location.hash = "#" + $divs[ Math.floor(Math.random() * $divs.length) ].id;

which appears to work!

The user will have two options, to choose their own assignment, or to let the app choose.
Thank you for the help!

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry, I should've thought to use `location.hash` in the first place, but before I posted my answer I ran a quick test of my code and it worked as is in IE so at that point I stopped thinking about that and moved on to the hide/show part of my answer...

Comment: hey, no problem.  without help from awesome people like you, there is no way I could do this!
Noel

Comment: any idea if you can have multiple classes? For example, I have the assignment class and it works awesome with the random script.  can I give the same div another class name to work with a different random script? for example, <class name=subject>

Comment: You can definitely give multiple classes to the same element. In your html just list them separated by spaces: `<div class="class1 class2 class3 etc" />`. As far as adding extra classes dynamically, the jQuery functions `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()` only add/remove the class(es) you specify while leaving any other classes alone (see the jQuery doco).

Comment: So just to be clear, if I put in <div class="assignment subject color">, when i use the above script to call "assignment", it will pick up this div...if I create another script to call "subject", it will pick up this div...etc...

Comment: Yep. The jQuery selector `$(".subject")` will pick up any element with the "subject" class regardless of what other classes those elements may or may not have.

Comment: Thanks again for the help.  Just wondering, is there a way to trigger this script in a div when that div is selected?
For example, if I have a link to a DIV called random, when it opens/loads/shows (whatever the correct term is), how do I launch the script so it automatically selects a random div and shows that one?
I've tried this script as a button in the footer for my app, but it doesnt seem to work. 
Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Can't you trigger the function from the link you mention?

Comment: I'm trying to add a button to the footer in each div that will run the script you gave me to link to a random div.
I put this line in:
<input id="getAssignment" type="button" value="Get assignment">
but it wont run the script.
that's why I thought I could maybe just link to a DIV that has the script in it, but how do I trigger it?  I'm really a newb when it comes to coding... :)

Comment: ok, so I've figured out that it only seems to let me call the function once...
If I add the script again, but change           

    $(".getAssignment").click(function() {
to
    $(".getAssignment2").click(function() {
and then call it with 
   <input id="getAssignment2" type="button" value="Get assignment">
but this would appear to mean that I'd have to add the script to each footer div and change the number...

Comment: No, don't use ids, use a common class and include the script exactly once. Have a look at the html I included at the end of my update, and you'll see the buttons have the _same_ class as each other and no id. The updated jQuery code uses a class selector `".getAssignment"` to put a click on all of them. Within the click handler, `this` gives you a reference to the one that was actually clicked.

Comment: thank you, I was able to actually get it to work by changing the original suggestion you had> I changed from "#getAssignment" to ".getAssignment" and called it by <input class="getAssignment"> instead of <input id>

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't posted any HTML, there are several possibilities.  First one, list all the relevant IDs in a javascript array and pick one randomly:

```
var items = [
   "id1",
   "id2",
   "id3"
];

var randomItemId = items[Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length)];
```

Then, access if with jQuery:

```
$("#" + randomItemId)
```

Second, if all the relevant divs have the same class name, you can do it like this:

```
var items = $(".whateverClassName");
var randomItemNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length);
var randomItem = items.eq(randomItemNum);
```

Comment: This is essentially the same as the answer given in the link on the question. The difference is that this method will prevent you from getting divs that you don't want (like the one containing the button they click) as well.
You'll want to put the "var randomItem = items[Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length)];
" in the click handler of the button, and the other is just static initialization (so basically anywhere that the other can access it).